# How can I show transformation of coordinate grid lines in python?

Tags: python, math, visualization

Suppose I have the regular cartesian coordinate system $(x,y)$ and I consider a rectangular mesh region $D$ (split into little squares). I want to see how the domain D would be mapped under a coordinate transform T:(x,y) -> (u(x,y) ,v(x,y) ) in Python?

I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

[See here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves%2FAnalysis%2FComplex_Variables_with_Applications_(Orloff)%2F01%253A_Complex_Algebra_and_the_Complex_Plane%2F1.08%253A_Complex_Functions_as_Mappings).

Could I be advised on how this could be done? I am a total beginner at python and programming.

Comment: So you'd like to draw two figures, with the arrow in between, in a single plot?

Comment: Why specifically Python, if you are new to programming?

Comment: That, I searched on the internet "simplest programming language" then I found python was the one @9769953

Comment: Well "draw to figures".. not quite it. I have the domain on the left grid, and I want to see how the contour lines and the domain as a whole gets mapped under the transformation

Comment: @9769953 for this problem, Python is not a bad choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to see a sort of a grid plot of a transformed cartesian space? In that case, maybe something like this, using Numpy and Matplotlib. (You could do the same with just Pillow to draw some lines, but this is more convenient...)

**EDIT:** Following the discussion in the comments, I changed this a bit compared to the simpler original (see edit history), to make it easier to plot multiple transformations, as well as to color the lines to make it easier to follow how they're transformed. It's still *pretty* simple, though. (For fun, I also threw in a couple of extra transformations.)

```
import math

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

colormap = cm.get_cmap("rainbow")


def plot_grid(
    xmin: float,
    xmax: float,
    ymin: float,
    ymax: float,
    n_lines: int,
    line_points: int,
    map_func,
):
    """
    Plot a transformation of a regular grid.

    :param xmin: Minimum x value
    :param xmax: Maximum x value
    :param ymin: Minimum y value
    :param ymax: Maximum y value
    :param n_lines: Number of lines per axis
    :param line_points: Number of points per line
    :param map_func: Function to map the grid points to new coordinates
    """
    # List for gathering the lines into.
    lines = []

    # Iterate over horizontal lines.
    for y in np.linspace(ymin, ymax, n_lines):
        lines.append([map_func(x, y) for x in np.linspace(xmin, xmax, line_points)])

    # Iterate over vertical lines.
    for x in np.linspace(xmin, xmax, n_lines):
        lines.append([map_func(x, y) for y in np.linspace(ymin, ymax, line_points)])

    # Plot all the lines.
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        p = i / (len(lines) - 1)  # Normalize to 0-1.
        # Transpose the list of points for passing to plot.
        xs, ys = zip(*line)
        # Get the line color from the colormap.
        plt.plot(xs, ys, color=colormap(p))


# Define some mapping functions.


def identity(x, y):
    return x, y


def example(x, y):
    c = complex(x, y) ** 2
    return (c.real, c.imag)


def wobbly(x: float, y: float):
    return x + math.sin(y * 2) * 0.2, y + math.cos(x * 2) * 0.3


def vortex(x: float, y: float):
    dst = (x - 2) ** 2 + (y - 2) ** 2
    ang = math.atan2(y - 2, x - 2)
    return math.cos(ang - dst * 0.1) * dst, math.sin(ang - dst * 0.1) * dst


# Set up the plot surface...
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.tight_layout()

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.title("Identity")
plot_grid(0, 4, 0, 4, 10, 10, identity)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.title("Example")
plot_grid(0, 4, 0, 4, 10, 10, example)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.title("Wobbly")
plot_grid(0, 4, 0, 4, 10, 40, wobbly)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.title("Vortex")
plot_grid(0, 4, 0, 4, 10, 40, vortex)

plt.savefig("so71735261-2.png")
plt.show()
```

The result image is:
[image]

Comment: Quick question how do I change the function? For example how do I put sin(z)

Comment: Change what's inside get_point.

Comment: I see, I think the reason I got confused is that we don't know how the initial mesh looked like before we mapped it to the final one (different meshes give different mapped results). Could there be anyway to include that on the side?

Comment: Of course, just a moment...

Comment: @Buraian Please see edit :-)

Comment: Wow! I was actually doubting if programming would help me do the things I Wanted but your answer is 100% convinced me that programming will allow me to do exactly what I want. While I can use your answer, I can't understand it yet. I am will be spending a long time on understanding all the commands and syntax you've used. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Buraian I'm glad I could help! (As an aside, the holeless cow deformation in your profile gave me a chuckle, so thanks for that!)

Answer (score -3):

It's not completely trivial. You need to learn how to use a plotting library to create the plots, e.g. matplotlib. You also need to figure out how to create, discretize and transform your regular grid. The numpy library is very useful for such operations. Anyway, I'm not sure this is such a good problem for a "total beginner". I'd advise to start with something simpler, if you don't know programming or Python at all.

Comment: Actually the motivation is that I am trying to go over a book known as Visual Complex Analysis by Tristan Needham. It is suggested in the book to use computer programs to plot the complex functions many times. Many of the programs which were suggested in the book are unvailable now/ not free to use, so I wanted to see how If this was posisble through python only

Comment: If you could perhaps give me a road map of the things I need to know to solve this problem , then that would be really great. This is something I really want to do.

Comment: The roadmap would be 1) learn the basics of Python and then 2) learn to use the matplotlib and numpy libraries. If you try to learn these (pretty big and complex) libraries without knowing the basics of Python first, it will probably just lead to frustration.

Comment: I've gone over the libraries and while they do seem related I can't exactly see how I could equipped with the knowledge of those libraries solve this situation.

Comment: Could you perhaps give me more specific advice if you could? And perhaps where I could learn those things

Comment: I would start by defining a regular grid of complex numbers (representing grid points) in a numpy array, then transform it into another array using the desired complex operation. Then I would try to plot both arrays as a bunch of curves, probably using some kind of interpolation between the calculated points to get smooth curves.  For an experienced user of these libraries, it wouldn't be too hard. But I don't think it's a good first problem.

Comment: I'm confused a bit here, array is a discrete block of numbers right? So how does one go from that to a curve?

Comment: Well, you can't. A curve has an infinite number of points, and computers cannot represent that. But you can determine a limited number of points on the curve. If you use a sufficiently large amount of points, it will start looking like a smooth curve.

Comment: @trystwithfreedom ignore this "non-answer". If all the answers to questions such as "how do I solve problem X" was "go learn how to solve problem X", the exchange forums such as this would have been a complete joke. And the audacity to put this as an answer and not a comment...

Comment: @MathX you're entitled to your opinion. However, to me the question is a bit like asking "How do I solve Schrödinger's equation for the hydrogen atom? I'm a total beginner at math and physics." The answer is that you need build up a lot of foundational knowledge first. Of course someone can show you the solution, but will you learn anything useful that way?