# Smoothly mapping one grid into another using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, matplotlib-animation

I have been working on a project of visualising how a grid transforms to another one by applying some function. Here is an example:

[image: Result of applying some function to the original square grid]

The work is heavily inspired in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71735261/how-can-i-show-transformation-of-coordinate-grid-lines-in-python) . What I wanted to do next is, using *matplotlib*, create some animation that smoothly turns the original grid (labeled "identity" in the image above) into the final grid (labeled "example"). However, I have very little knowledge of the *matplotlib* library and its uses to animations. Can someone point to good resources or write a "skeleton", *i.e.* synthetic, code of how to proceed?

I have been able to animate more simple things with *matplotlib*, like the graph of a function. However, in this example I have to somehow keep the information about, for instance, the color of each line while animating. Here is the code for the *update*/*animate* function of *matplotlib*'s *animation* class:

```
def update(frame):
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        p = i / (len(lines) - 1)  # Normalize to 0-1.
        # Transpose the list of points for passing to plot.
        xs, ys = zip(*line)
        x = [frame*x for x in xs]
        y = [frame * y for y in ys]
        # Get the line color from the colormap.
        plt.plot(x, y, color=colormap(p))
```

However, the screen fills up with lines (which may be easy to fix since I just have to clean the screen after each frame (?)) and the result is not what I expected.

Thank you in advance.